# Report test failures directly into github in a Salesforce/Github CI environment?

Tags: github, ci

Wondering if any wizards out there possess code or a recipe that, upon a pull request, executes all tests and reports failures directly back into Github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think creating a batch file containing commands in the following order would help:

Step 1. Pull the metadata from github

Step 2. Use the ant salesforce migration tool to run test on your salesforce org and get that output in a text file.

Step 3. Commit and push that textfile to github.

Run the batch file after every pull request.